# how print in python loop with space and without new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want space between every number and a new line between two different numbers.

**My code:**

```
num = [4 , 2]
for item in num:
   for i in range(item):
      print(item ,end="")
```

**Desired output:**

```
4 4 4 4
2 2
```

**Current output:**

```
444422
```

Comment: Why? It's much easier to just construct a string that will print this way than trying to mess around with the `sep` and `end` arguments of the `print` function.

Comment: Either way, you need to use `end=" "` and then an empty `print()` after the inner `for` loop. It's not possible to do what you want using only the `sep` and `end` arguments.

Comment: @ddejohn in the end in last one i have extra space like 4 4 4 4" "

Comment: Your requirement that you do not want a newline in the output is contradictory to your desired output which *requires* a newline, one way or another. Why exactly do you want to avoid using a newline anyway? Also, are you talking about the `\n` character? Or having to use an extra print statement? Right now, your question doesn't make a lot of sense, and doesn't add much value to the site.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `end=""`, what exactly do you think this part means? Notice how, when the code is written like that - when it says that the `end` value should be a string with nothing in it - nothing is printed after the `item` value. What do you want to print instead of the empty value? Therefore, can you think of something else that could be used for `end`, in order to get that result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
num = [4 , 2]
for item in num:
  for i in range(item):
    print(item, end=" ")
  print()
```

**Edit:**

I think it's overcomplicated for a problem like this, but you can try (it shouldn't print extra space at the end):

```py
num = [4 , 2]
for item in num:
  for i in range(item):
    if item - 1 == i:
      print(item)
    else:
      print(item, end=" ")
```

It prints an item with a new line when it's the last number in the second loop otherwise it prints the number with a space.

Comment: have extra space in the end every line

Comment: @elseadawy you need to learn about string formatting and `str.join`.

Comment: @elseadawy I think the second code should work I tested it and it shouldn't have extra space in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "\n" which creates a new line as follow:

```
num = [4 , 2]
for item in num:
   for i in range(item):
      print(item, end=" ")
   print("\n")
```

Make sure the end has space in it; like " " instead of ""

Answer (score -1):

Another approach with just 1 line of code inside `for` loop and not extra conditions:

```
num = [4 , 2]
for item in num:
    # [str(item)]*item creates a list with 'item' repeated 'item' no. of time.
    # Join this list with a space
    print (" ".join([str(item)]*item))
```

Output:

```
4 4 4 4
2 2
```